# Параметры, маршрутизация express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, маршрутизация

Задана обработка такого маршрута:

```
app.get('/users/:username', (req, res) => {
    let username = req.params.username;
    // ...
});
```

Всё работает, если никнейм `username` не содержит каких-то специальных символов. То есть при переходе по ссылке `http://localhost/users/Don2Quixote` в переменную `username` будет записано верное значение. Если же никнейм выглядит как-то так: new_user#0003, то часть "#0003" отбрасывается, в переменную `username` идёт только `new_user`.

Более того, если использовать `req.originalUrl`, вывод будет таким: `/users/new_user`; Смею предположить, нужно использовать URL Encode?

Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, что следует после octothorpe (символ `#`), не отсылается на сервер (если речь про `GET` запрос). Оно доступно только на клиенте через `window.location.hash`, если речь про js.

Если у вас переменная содержит подобные спец.символы, то закодируйте с помощью чего-нить типо `encodeURIComponent()`.

Или же передавайте их не через `query`.